# Search Books from Publisher in Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-product-api

Does anyone know how i can request all books from a publisher with  the amazon product api?

Which operation,parameter,response group must i use?

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the latter versions of the API Amazon only allows you to pull a limited numer of response pages, probably to stop people from doing just that. You can get more results if you vary the categories (i.e. BrowseNodes).